# How to display two values in text_field Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need textfield in Rails:

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, placeholder: :first_name , :class => 'form-control', "disabled" => "disabled" %>
```

I want to display two variables in one text field:

```
:first_name :second_name
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, value: "#{f.object.first_name} #{f.object.second_name}", autofocus: true, placeholder: :first_name , :class => 'form-control', "disabled" => "disabled" %>
```

Comment: undefined method `first_name' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fcb2ae89b10>

Comment: Either you've missed out `.object` or the object the form is bound to doesn't have a `first_name` method

Answer (score 2):

You should have in you model a method that concatenates `first_name` and `second_name`:

```
def full_name 
  "#{self.first_name}, #{self.second_name}"
end
```

And then call it in you view like that:

```
<%= f.text_field :full_name, autofocus: true, placeholder: :first_name , :class => 'form-control', "disabled" => "disabled" %>
```